# Deleting UnsortedSequenceTable in abstract class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract, derived-class

I tried to delete my custom UnsortedSequenceTable in abstract class, which is derived by other classes... It is possible to delete the content in destructor? (Yes I have implementation of Iterators). Or I must try something else?

(I must delete the content at the end of the program. Because otherwise it gives me a plenty of memory leaks.)

```
template<typename O, typename T, typename H>
class Filter_fi : public Filter<O, T, H>
{
public:
    Filter_fi() {};
    void setAlpha(T pAlpha) { alphaPARAM = pAlpha; };
    T getAlpha() { return alphaPARAM; };

    UnsortedSequenceTable<H, O*> vyfiltruj(UnsortedSequenceTable<H, O*> pVstup, Kriterium<O, T>& pKriterium) override {

        table = new UnsortedSequenceTable<H, O*>;
        for (TableItem<H, O*>* prem : pVstup) {
            if (splnaFilter(*prem->accessData(), pKriterium)) {
                table->insert(prem->getKey(), prem->accessData());
            }

        }
        return *table;

    }



    virtual ~Filter_fi(){

        for (TableItem<H, O*>* prem : table) { --> ERROR

            delete prem->accessData(); --> ERROR

        };
    };
```